# What is the range of id for open groups (not the channel) in Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telethon

Created an open group whose id is -1001492565750, somewhere I read that -100 is the id of the group entity, real id is 1 492 565 750, maybe someone knows the exact range, decided to check the id of its various groups and I got about 1 340 000 000 to 1 590 000 000.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram ID's can be bigger than ***`2^31 - 1`***.
<sup>(2.147.483.647)</sup>

---

From the [Telegram Bot API 5.1 Change log](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#march-9-2021):
<sup>March 9, 2021</sup>

> **⚠️ WARNING! ⚠️**
>
> After one of the upcoming Bot API updates, some user identifiers will become bigger than `2^31 - 1` and ***it will be no longer possible to store them in a signed 32-bit integer type***. User identifiers will have up to 52 significant bits, so a 64-bit integer or double-precision float type would still be safe for storing them.
> Please make sure that your code can correctly handle such user identifiers.